# Hide lines in odoo treeview

Tags: treeview, odoo, odoo-10

I want to hide equipments that are not in an inventory. I've tried with

```
<record id="view_inventory_equipment_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">maintenance.equipment.tree</field>
    <field name="model">maintenance.equipment</field>
    <field name="domain">[('inventory_id','=',False)]</field>

    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Lot/Serial Number Inventory">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="serial_no"/>
            <field name="category_id"/>
            <field name="inventory_id"/>
            <field name="cost"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

But that did not work, also there is no luck with

```
<field name="domain_force">[('inventory_id','=',False)]</field>
```

My model:

```
class MaintenanceEquipment(models.Model):
    _name = 'maintenance.equipment'
    _description = 'Equipment'

    name = fields.Char('Equipment Name', required=True, translate=True)

    inventory_id = fields.Many2one('maintenance.equipment.inventory', string='Equipment Inventory', track_visibility='onchange')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put domain in action window record. Domain not work in directly with any view like tree or form view.